# how can I get the value in this page in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to get the value from webpage using selenium base on python. However, I do not get the point about how to make it. The value I want to catch is in the red mark side of below picture. Please help me to figure out this. Thank you very much!

[Please click here to check the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dggov.jpg)

Comment: Can you share your code trials?

Comment: Also please share your HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few ways (By css,by xpath...) I recommend you reading this page: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html

You also need some understanding about html, css and the DOM but the simplest way to get the value you want is by xpath (But its the slowest)

Open your web browser lets say chrome, right click on the element you want and inspect. It will open developer tools and you will have the html line selected already, right click it again-> copy -> copy xpath

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver') 
driver.get("http://www.web.com")
driver.find_element_by_xpath(the_xpath_you_copied_before_from_dev_tools).text
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I have caught the value by using the code you provided : )